# Como formatar o print de uma tabuada no terminal para que ela sempre ocupe o mesmo espaço horizontal em cada linha?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação, terminal

```
for i in range (0, 11):
    for j in range(0, 11):
        print(f'* {i} x {j} = {i*j:} *')
    print()
    print('*'*15)
```

Preciso que o output seja com o asterisco à direita alinhado com o asterisco debaixo e de cima

Answer (score 3):

Veja na especificação da [Minilinguagem de especificação de formato](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) que para números o operador `>` força o alinhamento à direita do campo dentro do espaço disponível.

```python
for i in range (0, 11):
    for j in range(0, 11):
        print(f'* {i:>3} x {j:>3} = {i*j:>3} *') 
    print()
    print('*'*19)
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/TabTabuada)</sup>

Comment: Precisava mesmo colocar esse output grande na resposta?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, como sugere que seja a apresentação?

Comment: Você poderia reduzir o output, deixando uma amostra de 3 linhas da tabuada, ou então retirar o output da resposta e deixar que o próprio AP execute o código, no link do Repl.it que você deixou, e veja por si mesmo.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002, melhorou?

Comment: Sim, está melhor.